# Are local admin rights required to install Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, installation

Can anyone provide an emphatic answer as to whether local admin rights are required to install the Silverlight 3 client? Most of the Google results say “yes” (with some conflicting answers), but I’ve just tested this on several Win XP machines and installation was definitely successful without admin rights.

Just to be crystal clear, the machines I’ve tested are in a corporate managed desktop environment and users most definitely do not have local admin rights. A “net localgroup Administrators” command confirms they’re not in this group.

Can anyone absolutely confirm either way? Thanks.

Comment: For XP, did you try the reduced "Guest" account? For Vista and Windows 7, local administrative rights are definitely required, or the use of management software for an organization to deploy the bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, local administrative rights are required.

Comment: So any idea why it installs successfully on XP without local admin? I'm just seeing something different to what I keep reading.

Comment: It's possible that the corporate rights management system permits installations of Microsoft-signed software, or similar measures...

Answer (score 0):

Admin rights are required.
By default XP users are local admins.

Comment: In the circumstances I've described above, users do not have admin rights. It's a corporate managed desktop environment with limited user rights.