# Silverlight 4 - does install require administrator privileges?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to figure out if installing the Silverlight 4 client requires local administrators rights.  Some pages seem to indicate that it does, but others that it doesn't.  I've had already seen this question:

[Are local admin rights required to install Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529130/are-local-admin-rights-required-to-install-silverlight)

However, I'm asking against for two reasons.  One, this is Silverlight 4 so I'm wondering if the situation has changed.  Two, I'm hoping to get a link to some official documentation that states this, as opposed to just getting a "Yes it does." answer.

I've done some testing, and from what I can tell my users are able to install it *without* local admin rights but I'm in a corporate environment with a complex security profile so I'm not sure what the actual settings are.

This is with Internet Explorer 6 if it matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does.

The following link contains resources for Silverlight in general:

http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/resources/

The "Silverlight Enterprise Deployment Guide" is the document you are looking for:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/D/5/CD5AAAE3-21F7-47A8-B7D5-39E36BAF9AC8/Silverlight_Deployment_Guide.docx

This document is updated for SL4.

Page 22 of this document states that a user must be members of the Administrators group if they are installing it by themselves.

Comment: Exactly the kind of detailed answer I was looking for.  Thanks.  However, it still doesn't jive with the experimental installs I've done with users that are not local admins.

Comment: @jkohlhepp: I am not an infra guy, but have you checked to see if there isn't a policy in place already?

Comment: No I haven't.  It is surprisingly difficult to navigate the corporate maze to find the one guy who would be able to give me an answer to that. :-)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something p22 just says the auto-updater needs admin rights. I don't see a blanket statement about the installer in general.